# Python: Counter not taking class name of namedtuple into account ... how do I fix?

Tags: python

```
>>> Employee = namedtuple("Employee", "name")
>>> Patient = namedtuple("Patient", "name")
>>> e = Employee("Mike")
>>> p = Patient("Mike")
>>> Counter([e, p])
Counter({Employee(name='Mike'): 2})
```

Why doesn't the Counter differentiate between the two classes of namedtuple?

Answer (score 4):

Namedtuples are, as the name implies, tuples.  They are compared elementwise.  Since both of your tuples have `"Mike"` as the first (and only) element, they are equal.  It doesn't matter that they're different classes; only the contents are compared.

If you want to take account of the class itself in comparison, you'd have to write your own wrapper class.  (One simple possibility would be to make a wrapper that includes the class name as an element of the tuple, so employee-Mike would become `("Employee", "Mike")` and patient-Mike would be `("Patient", "Mike")`.)

Comment: Easier to wrap a namedtuple or modify, say, an Employee class's hash to evalute to hash(('Employee', name))?

Comment: @MikeRand: It's not enough to modify the hash, you would have to also modify `__eq__` if your Patient class also used `name` to store its name.  Otherwise the employee and patient will still compare equal.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Sorry, what I meant was that there would be a base class that would have `__hash__ = hash((self.__class__.__name__, ?))` where ? is some sequence of attributes. I would expect the inclusion of `self.__class__.__name__` would allow Employee and Patient to differentiate themselves in a dictionary, right?

Comment: @MikeRand: No, as I said, modifying `__hash__` is not enough.  You must also modify `__eq__` to have a compatible definition.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984473/python-dictionary-conundrum/13984519#13984519).